# return multiple row when i have multiple ids in csv format in mysql

Tags: mysql

i know it may be very simple query, but please help me out.

```
    i have item id 1,2,3,4 etc....
```

now i want to get all row regrading that item id
 what will be mysql query?? i used `IN` operator but this return only one row

```
SELECT item_id,item_name FROM tbl_item_detail WHERE item_id IN('1,3,4')
```

my table structure is below

```
item_id | item_name |.....
  1     |  first    |
  2     |  second   |
  3     |  third    |
  4     |  fourth   |
```

.          .

which operator i have to use?or what will be perfect query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After firing this query, mysql would have returned two things:
1. The item_id, item_name of the row with id 1 in the tbl_item_detail table.
2. A warning after the above result like, '1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00sec)'.

The warning message means that there was a problem in your query, and mysql could only partially understand it. Your query was:

```
SELECT item_id,item_name FROM tbl_item_detail WHERE item_id IN('1,3,4');
```

It should actually be:

```
SELECT item_id,item_name FROM tbl_item_detail WHERE item_id IN(1,3,4);
```

OR

```
SELECT item_id,item_name FROM tbl_item_detail WHERE item_id IN('1','3','4');
```

I believe the rest is self explanatory.